# Ambiguous grammar

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, ambiguous-grammar

I am looking at the following grammar and I believe its Ambiguous at line 3, but not sure.

```
<SL> → <S>
<SL> → <SL> <S>
<S> → i <B> <S> e <S>
<S> → i <B> <S> 
<S> → x
<S> → y
<B> → 5
<B> → 13
```

I found this string `xi13yi5xeyx` I believe generates two different parse trees, but I'm not sure if im doing it wrong.

Can some one please verify my findings?

Comment: Is this grammar written in Backus-Naur form, or is it written using another notation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes your grammar is an ambiguous grammar!
<sub>You have not mention But I think `<SL>` is start viable</sub>

Using your grammar rules we can draw more then one parse tree(*two*) for wring `i5i5yey` as followes:

```
       <SL>                              <SL>
        |                                 |  
       <S>                               <S>   
     / /|\ \                            / | \ 
    / / | \ \                          /  |  \
   / /  |  \ \                        /   |   \
  / /   |   \ \                      i   <B>   <S>      
 /  |   |   |  \                          |  / /|\ \     
 i <B> <S>  e  <S>                        5 / / | \ \
   /  / | \     |                          / /  |  \ \  
  /  /  |  \    y                         / /   |   \ \
 5  i  <B> <S>                           /  |   |   |  \  
        |   |                           i  <B> <S>  e  <S> 
        5   y                               |   |       |  
                                            5   y       y
```

Structure of both parse tree are different two the grammar is **an ambiguous grammar!**

You can extend above diagram to generate tree string `xi13yi5xeyx`, (*I am leaving this as an exercise for you*)

Important is the language generate by this grammar is [not ambiguous language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_grammar#Inherently_ambiguous_languages).And its possible to write an equivalent unambiguous grammar for this grammar that always generates unique tree for each string in language of grammar.

**HINT**: To write unambiguous grammar.

The grammar is quite similar to grammar for `if loop` in C language (notice different language having different syntax for `if loop`). and it solved in almost all compiler design book.
[**Resolving the General Dangling Else/If-Else Ambiguity**](http://www.parsifalsoft.com/ifelse.html)

Reference: ***Book*** Compilers Principles, Technique, and tools by Aho-Ullman **Section 4.5** conflicts During Shift and-Reduce Parsing.